# Reuse variable outside of composition - passing variables up in jsf?

Tags: jsf, variables, facelets, visibility, dry

I'm using jsf 1.2 and have got some weird javascript which gets repeated at several places in my project.

I do not want to repeat myself.. but i found no way to do something similar to this:

```
<ui:composition>
        <c:set var="confirmBlockJS" value="if (confirm('#{tk:encodeJS(confirmMessage)}')) {#{confirmed}} else{ #{notConfirmed}}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Now i want to use the set variable but obv this will fail.

```
                <ui:include src="/blocks/tech/confirmBlock.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="confirmMessage" value="#{appTexts['action.logout.title']}"/>
                    <ui:param name="confirmed" value="return false;"/>
                    <ui:param name="notConfirmed" value=" #{doJS}"/>
                </ui:include>
            <h:outputLink id="logout" value="#" rendered="#{renderLogout}"
                onclick='#{confirmBlockJS};'
                styleClass="_allowEnterKey">
                <h:outputText value="#{appTexts['action.logout']}"></h:outputText>
            </h:outputLink>
```

confirmBlockJS is obviously empty at that point, which is actually in my eyes a good thing. But is there no way to pass the variable up? I tried ui:param without luck.

**SOLUTION**
Use `ui:decorate` when you want to access variable set with `c:set` outside of the page which uses the `ui:decorate`. It will still be visible. In the case of ui:include the c:set will not be visible outside, but ui:param should pass it up (e.g. use ui:param instead of `c:set` in the `ui:include` composition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't want to inline it as an attribute value, then [`<ui:decorate>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/decorate.html) would be the solution for you.

An EL function is closest what you can get to work for this particular functional requirement:

```
<h:outputLink id="logout" value="#" rendered="#{renderLogout}"
    onclick="#{js:confirmBlock(appTexts['action.logout.title'], 'return false;', doJS)}"
    styleClass="_allowEnterKey">
    <h:outputText value="#{appTexts['action.logout']}"></h:outputText>
</h:outputLink>
```

or:

```
<ui:param name="confirmBlock" value="#{js:confirmBlock(appTexts['action.logout.title'], 'return false;', doJS)}" />
<h:outputLink id="logout" value="#" rendered="#{renderLogout}"
    onclick="#{confirmBlock}"
    styleClass="_allowEnterKey">
    <h:outputText value="#{appTexts['action.logout']}"></h:outputText>
</h:outputLink>
```

Note that generating JS code by Java/JSF/EL this way is a bit a smell. Is it really not possible to make it a simple JS function which you put in a `.js` file and parameterize it with arguments?

Comment: actually a simple js function might be the cleanest solution... the problem is that the text passed to the function MUST be escaped, especially french with their many ' causes us trouble. To my knowledge there is no way to enforce this without using some java function #{tk:encodeJS()}. Other ideas?
An EL function would be a possible solution as well. What I didn't quite get was your example with UI:param ... I use it to pass variables inside includes or decorates. So your second example must be inside a decorate with some define?

Comment: Then just use `#{tk:encodeJS()}` accordingly? As to the example with `<ui:param>`, it's just to create an "alias" for the case that the expression is lengthy and you would like to reuse it multiple times.

Comment: It's until today that I really understood the difference between ui:decorate and ui:include (e.g. different visibility of at least c:set). I don't know what went wrong when I tried my luck with my blocks but basically it should work :-)